# HTTP Error 403.503 - Forbidden IIS 10

Tags: asp.net, iis, windows-10, iis-10

I know this has been asked a thousand times... but I am still having problems, despite two days of trying!

This is running locally. **Even my localhost is giving me a 403!**

**My setup:**

- Windows 10 Pro
- IIS 10

Every site in IIS greets me with the old favourite 'HTTP Error 403.503 - Forbidden' error. I have fiddled with Application Pool settings, restarted, re-registered (aspnet_regiis -i), used 'run as administrator', added IUSER to security and gave full control, created a fresh MVC application in Visual Studio 2015 and added the site to IIS... I've tried everything I can think of!

Does anyone have a suggestion for me, before I delete Windows?

Comment: Are you sure its not related to IP address restrictions?  http://serverfault.com/questions/659105/what-is-the-meaning-of-an-iis-http-status-code-404-503

Comment: @BrendanGreen In `IP Address and Domain Restrictions` I have tried with both my IP as obtained via ipconfig and with no entries ;(

Comment: @pookie you completely misunderstood the ServerFault thread. http://www.iis.net/learn/get-started/whats-new-in-iis-8/iis-80-dynamic-ip-address-restrictions open Dynamic Restriction settings and uncheck the boxes. Adding IP addresses to the list is for static restriction.

Comment: @LexLi & BrendanGreen. Thank you. The default was to deny, which makes sense, except for the fact that I had explicitly added an allow rule with my IP -- I would expect that to work. It's working now, but I have removed all rules and set 'Access for unspecified clients' to 'Allow'.

Answer (score 16):

I was getting "HTTP Error 403.503 - Forbidden" as well with details`Module     IpRestrictionModule
Notification       BeginRequest
Handler    ExtensionlessUrlHandler-Integrated-4.0
Error Code     0x80070005`

The fix for me was to go to IIS, click on site, click on IP Address and Domain Restrictions, clicking 'Edit Feature Settings', the selecting 'Allow' (instead of deny)

Comment: thank you that was works for me by set Edit Feature Settings to allow

Comment: I looked in the IP Address and Domain Restrictions so many times but there were no rules  there so I stopped looking. This brought hours of head scratching to and end thank you.

Comment: This means you turn the whitelist into a blacklist.

Answer (score 0):

In my case the admin had added IP Restrictions for their public IP's.
So the site was accessible outside the server, but not on the server.

So I had to add the IP of the server itself to the list in order to browse on the physical server.